# Interpretation of certain maps related to weather

Tags: meteorology

I am a student Pilot and basically we are asked to give weather briefing every morning using the charts shown here:
https://mausam.imd.gov.in/imd_latest/contents/satellite.php#.
https://mausam.imd.gov.in/imd_latest/contents/index_radar.php?id=Lucknow

The problem is, nobody has any idea how to actually interpret these charts in a useful and correct manner, leading people to just say what they've always been hearing in the morning briefing. This could be detrimental to the safety of the trainee pilots here.

So is there some sort of manual and/or any book which states how to analyse these charts? It'd be of great help if someone could answer, thanks!

Comment: The radar shows current/recent precipitation, the main satellite (visible/IR) shows current/recent clouds (not always great at fog)... brightness can suggest convection depth (the intensity of storms) and water vapor can be useful for diagnosing upper level system development and such.  Perhaps they two sites would either be better as separate questions, depending on what more you want to know about them... or include some additional sites (as usually to make a complete weather briefing you'll want to include things like surface observations and perhaps models?)

Comment: Or maybe an idea of what factors to discuss as they are of course broad topics!  Have done quite a few weather briefings, but not to pilots, so not sure what specific things are most important.

Comment: Although a fair answer can probably be put together on the question as it stands if not.  Though the broadness is a fair challenge... it'd like me as a meteorologist saying "what's the deal with this picture of a certain airtcraft's controls, what's important/how do I analyze it to fly... there can be some basics hit upon, but a comprehensive answer is beyond the scope of a short explanation

Comment: I don't know of any specific manuals or books, though I'm sure some exists.

Comment: you should google "how to read a weather map with explanations"and follow the links that all of the weather services provide to find more information.as on every SE site you need to show that you have tried to research the topic in your question before asking it here.